# android native plugin seems unusable

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to Unity development. I have followed many different tutorials regarding the use of native plugins in Unity. Those which consist in compiling .dll libraries and running them in the editor work just fine.

But compiling a .so file using android NDK and calling it in a C# script in Unity seems impossible. Even with [this trival example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html), it always throws DllNotFoundException. The library in this example doesn't include anything else, so the problem can't be that I'm missing additionnal libraries.

I'm using Unity 2018.3.7f1, and made sure that the libraries are marked as Android compatible, as well as having a Build set for Android. My machine is Windows 10.

[Edit] : I tried to deploy it on a samsung galaxy s7. The device is 64 bits so I had to make a few [changes](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) in the Unity Editor (select IL2CPP in the player settings etc.) I understand that Unity Editor will always throw errors since it is not able to detect the Android plugin. However the result in the Editor and on the device are the same, that is an empty blue screen. I figured the DllNotfound was the issue but now I realize this may not be the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you Trying to Run in Editor? If yes it will throw an exception. Try to take Build in Mobile

or you have to add Platform dependent compilation code to run without error in Editor

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR 
    [DllImport("native")]
    private static extern float add(float x, float y);
#endif
    void OnGUI ()
    {
        float x = 3;
        float y = 10;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        GUI.Label (new Rect (15, 125, 450, 100), "adding " + x  + " and " + y + " in native code equals " + add(x,y));

#endif
    }
```

Comment: Indeed it's in the editor that I see DllNotFoundException. However when building on mobile the message still doesn't appear... Which makes me believe that the issue is the same.

Comment: I tried building in 32 and 64 bit too to see if it made a difference. It doesn't seem to.

Comment: I tried both in editor and on device, and neither worked